# Pointers within class methods

Tags: c++, class, pointers

How do I make a pointer within a method of a class point to the object that the method is being called on?

I want to define a pointer in the body of a public method of a class and have it point to the instance of the object that the method is being called on.

Here's my code for some more context:

```
void Node::print() {
    Node *temp = this; //points to the node that calls the print function

    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        cout << "Name:  " << temp->name << "\tID:  " << temp->ID << endl;
        temp = temp->next; //makes temp->next point to the next node in the list.
    }

    //this line runs when temp->next == NULL
    cout << "Name:  " << temp->name << "\tID:  " << temp->ID << endl;
}
```

Comment: `auto self = this;` ?

Comment: I think keyword  [`this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) is what  you need.

Comment: ah so `this` refers to the instance of the class calling the method?

Comment: This is unclear. `this` might be what you're looking for (I doubt it), or what you're looking for might not exist (e.g. call happens in `main` or some other free function). Please describe your scenario in more detail.

Comment: @ryeguy00 Yes, it is.

Comment: @Mat The question clearly states "in the body of a public method of a class", which excludes `main`.

Comment: @Rhathin ok thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ryeguy00 *How do I make a pointer within a method of a class point to the object that is calling the method?* -- This is sounding more and more like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you want to know what object called the method?

Comment: @lisyarus: that's not how I understand it. I read it as they want, inside a member function, to get a pointer to "the instance of the object that calls the method". Sounds to like like they want a pointer to some sort of calling context.

Comment: @Mat I didn't see it that way. Indeed, the phrase "object that calls the method" is ambiguous.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added my code to the question.  Do you think there is a better solution for stepping through a linked list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of [`this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) pretty much describes what you are looking for:

> The keyword `this` is a prvalue expression **whose value is the address of the object, on which the member function is being called**.